# WebRTC RTCSessionDescription swift

Tags: swift, webrtc

I am trying to write a native iOS application using the WebRTC framework in swift. I have run into a problem since it seems the RTCSessionDescriptonDelegate has been deprecated and I can no longer really follow along this [tutorial](https://tech.appear.in/2015/05/25/Getting-started-with-WebRTC-on-iOS/).

I think I have gotten quite far but the main thing holding me back is I do not understand how to create an sdp parameter. 
RTCSessionDescription(type: .offer, sdp: )

If anyone could provide advice I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.0**

This is my solution for create SDP.

```
    let constraints: RTCMediaConstraints? = defaultPeerConnectionConstraints()
    peerConnection: RTCPeerCo = factory?.peerConnection(withICEServers: iceServers, constraints: constraints, delegate: self)
    let localStream: RTCMediaStream? = createLocalMediaStream() //get Media stream(video/audio)
    peerConnection?.add(localStream)

    //create offer for other opponent        

    if isInitiator {
        peerConnection?.createOffer(with: self, constraints: defaultOfferConstraints())
        print("create Offer")
    }
```

on ICE servers

```
func defaultICEServer() -> [RTCICEServer] {

  var iceServers = [RTCICEServer]()
  let defaultSTUNServerURL = URL(string: Config.defaultSTUNServerUrl)
  let defaultTURNServerURL = URL(string: Config.defaultTURNServerUrl)
  let stunServ = RTCICEServer(uri: defaultSTUNServerURL, username: "", password: "")
  let turnServ = RTCICEServer(uri: defaultTURNServerURL, username: "admin", password: "admin")
  iceServers.append(stunServ!)
  iceServers.append(turnServ!)

  return iceServers
}
```

and

```
 func defaultPeerConnectionConstraints() -> RTCMediaConstraints {
    let optionalConstraints: [Any] = [RTCPair(key: "DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", value: "true")]
    let constraints = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: nil, optionalConstraints: optionalConstraints)
    return constraints!
}
```

Then was call delegate

```
func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didCreateSessionDescription sdp: RTCSessionDescription, error: Error?) {}
```

Where you can use `sdp` for send other user. And you should set this `sdp` as `localDescription` for correct work.

```
peerConnection?.setLocalDescriptionWith(self, sessionDescription: sdp)
```

I hope, i can help

Comment: can you help further?